# How to detect when text is replaced in GtkTextBuffer instead of delete followed by insert?

Tags: c, gtk3

I have worked a great deal with the text system in Objective-C for macOS/iOS (e.g. NSTextView, NSTextStorage, etc.)  I am now experimenting with GTK3 to see how well I can translate my project for use on Linux, etc.

I am brand new to using GTK, but after a few days of Google time and experimenting, I have a working text editor prototype with my custom code plugged in.

The problem is this -- I need to be able to detect when a user highlights a section of text, and then replaces it with other text (e.g. a keystroke).  This is distinct from highlighting a section of text, hitting the delete key, and then typing the new text.  A specific use example would be highlighting a word, then typing a double quote character in order to wrap the word in quotes (e.g. `foo` becomes `"foo"`).

In Cocoa, one would receive `replaceCharactersInRange:` that indicates the range originally selected, as well as the new string to replace it with. I can then detect the presumed intent of the user based on the information received.

In GTK, it seems that we receive a `delete-range` signal, followed by a separate `insert-text` signal.  Because of this separation, the code in the "insert" section has no way of knowing that the user intended to replace text, not insert new text.

I used the following to receive the signals above:

```
g_signal_connect(buffer, "insert-text", G_CALLBACK(insert_text_cb), NULL);
g_signal_connect(buffer, "delete-range", G_CALLBACK(delete_range_cb), NULL);
```

Is there something else I can do in order to tell that there is a delete, followed by an insert as part of the same user action?

Thanks for any pointers offered!

Comment: I could detect the key-release itself, and override the behavior from that point, but that seems a bit "kludgy."  Am hoping for a better solution than that, but if necessary I can pursue it.

Comment: I suppose another option would be to somehow inspect the event-queue when processing the `delete-range` to determine whether it is immediately followed by an `insert-text` event.  Any pointers to make that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No answers over the last month, so I kept brainstorming and digging around.  I finally came up with this, which works, but is not quite as elegant as I had hoped.

1. Handle `delete-range` signal as before, but keep track of the the deleted text for later (e.g. in `char * deletedText`).
2. Handle the `insert-text` signal as before, but if we have a string in `deletedText` then change the behavior to perform a replacement instead of an insertion.  In my case, this actually meant inserting the deleted text back in, and then performing the replacement.
3. Add a callback for the `end-user-action` signal, which indicates that all delete/inserts associated with a particular action are complete.  In this callback, free `deletedText` from above and set to `NULL` (to indicate that everything has been handled).

Again -- this works, but feels a bit inelegant.  And depending on how complex your delete/insert routines are, it may slow the performance slightly since some steps have to be duplicated.  A better solution would be to detect during the `delete-range` callback that there is a pending `insert-text` callback and handle both steps at once.  I have thus far not been able to do that.

Comment: I have recently revisited my toy GTK project with a new version of the underlying library that includes more functionality.  In testing, I discovered that while this approach still works when typing a new character, it doesn't work when selecting existing text and then pasting new text in from the clipboard.  I don't think I tested that functionality before.  The error I get is " Gtk-WARNING **: Invalid text buffer iterator: either the iterator is uninitialized, or the characters/pixbufs/widgets in the buffer have been modified since the iterator was created."  Will have to dig further.

Comment: Turns out that I was doing some "clean up" to the GtkTextBuffer during the delete portion.  I migrated that to a callback on end-user-action instead, and that solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to correlate the delete and insert events, I would suggest creating a `GAction` for your desired action (e.g. toggle quotes around the selected text) and setting its shortcut key to <kbd>"</kbd> using `gtk_application_set_accels_for_action()`.

For more information, check out this [HowDoI](https://developer.gnome.org/GAction/) wiki page.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work, as the quote shortcut is just one example of many custom actions that could be triggered by various keystrokes.  The goal was to contain all of the logic in a separate C library, that can then be referenced from any text handling "widget" -- NSTextStorage on Mac, GTKTextBuffer, etc.

Comment: But couldn't you make `GActions` for each of those, in the GTK part of your code, which call into the separate logic library?

Comment: In theory yes, but that would require manually updating the GTK code for each change in the library, defeating the purpose of isolating that code in the library in the first place.